# Array of Array List by reading data from Excel using Java

Tags: java, excel, arraylist

I am trying to read data from the excel and sort it in 2 dimensional arraylist.
So that i can pass this array list to the function as parameter.

Could you please let me know how to create a 2 dimensional arraylist?

Working code would be of great help.

Example
If i pass the "test1" as parameter to the readExcel(), It should return a 2 dimensional array list.

Thanks and Regards,
Gajendra

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `List<List<String>>` and read and write from it.

```
//Create List<List<String>>
int size = 10;
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
     list.add(new ArrayList<String>());  //Create the lists and add to the 2D list
}
```

You can then read and write values to the list as follows:

```
list.get(0).set(1, "Hello");  // Insert hello at (0,1)
String value = list.get(0).get(1);  // Get the value at (0,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

An `ArrayList` of `ArrayList` is something like this :

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

You can declare a `List` of `List`.

```
List<List<Object>> list;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 List<List<String>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

And then when you want to add a new "row", you can add new row like this.

```
listOfLists.add(new ArrayList<String>());
```

For more details of [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)